# .wmf image not printing in .docx file from JasperSoft 6.3

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.3.0.final. I use the image expression to print image from relative path.

When I export into PDF, image is coming. In case of .docx Image not coming.

When I am adding .wmf image , image not exported into .docx file.

Is this a bug or any configuration need to do in JasperSoft?

Can you please let me know, do I need to set any other configuration for .docx?

Here I am attaching the jrxml code.

```
    <image onErrorType="Blank">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="41" y="141" width="130" height="139" uuid="d5febafb-320c-445f-97dd-d2f5f87d80c6"/>
    <graphicElement fill="Solid"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{GRAFIK}]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

Comment: Petter I accepted the answer. I did not know earlier. Thanks for informing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.wmf` seems to not be supported correctly, see jasper-reports acknowledged [bug report](http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-server/issues/8321).

I would suggest that you convert the **.wmf** file to **.svg** that is fully supported for all standard exports.

If you need to convert it at runtime, you can use the [xmlgraphics batik library](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/download.html), it have the [WMFTranscoder API](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/javadoc/org/apache/batik/transcoder/wmf/tosvg/WMFTranscoder.html) that can convert from  `wmf` to `svg`

Comment: Any sample example or reference can you tell ?
I am using sql query. I do not have that much idea in java.

Comment: @pmartha the WMFTranscoder API link have an example on how to convert from wmf to svg, but know doubts you need to know some java. You need to make a class and included this class in jasper-reports classpath.

Comment: @pmartha I saw you passed a bug report so I have edit the link into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yours JRXML code has been written right. I think it is bug or it is not supported. But `Microsoft Office >=2010` has been supporting import from PDF document, so you can do it through it.

I recommend you ask on Jaspersoft community, where the staff is answering and, if you pay for support, you should try Jaspersoft studio support.

Comment: I am using office 2013. When I set scaleImage="FillFrame" , in this case document is coming corrupt mode. but wmf image is printing.